# Generate a live preview of a Post as it's being created/edited in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

In my Rails app I have a pretty standard `post` model (with a `title` and `content`).

I want the user to be able to see a live preview of the `post_content` textarea as they are creating/editing the post.

What is the best way to do this? I'm not even sure where to start (other than likely with Javascript).

I've got it working with a preview button; however, I'd like the preview to automatically refresh itself whenever the user presses a key on the keyboard (basically refreshing as they type/make changes).

Any ideas / feedback is appreciated.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
<button id="preview-btn">Preview</button>
```

JS:

```
$('#preview-btn').on('click', function () {
    $('#preview').html($('#widget').val());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to fire the function on key change:

```
$('#input_field_id').on('input', function () {
    $('#preview').html($('#widget').val());
});
```